# unable to Convert const char* table[] to NSArray in IOS for unity

Tags: c++, ios, unity-game-engine

Inside .mm I have some code as shown below.

```js
extern "C"
{
    
    void _AddNotification(const char* title,
                          const char* body,
                          const char* cancelLbl,
                          const char* firstLbl,
                          const char* secondLbl,
                          const char* tables[])
    {
  
        
      
     }
}
```

How can I get const char* table[] data into NSArray.Can anyone please help me.I couldn't find any solution for this in online.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` only supports objects that are a type of `NSObject`, its subclasses. You will need to convert your values to `NSString` for instance using `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cString]`. Or `NSData` like `[NSData dataWithBytes:pointer length:sizeInBytes]`. You can also play around with `NSValue`.

But in general it depends what is it you want to put inside your array.

**EDIT: From comment "Can we get the count from const char* tables[]?"**

You can not get that in your case by normal means.

Consider this array of strings:

```
static const char *table[] = {
    "text a",
    "text b",
    "text c",
    "text d"
};
```

Now if you have a direct access to the `table` you may get count by using `sizeof` doing:

```
int numberOfStringsInTable = sizeof(table)/sizeof(char*);
```

This will return 4. But as soon as we add a new variable such as in function

```
int tableLength(const char *stringTable[]) {
    return sizeof(stringTable)/sizeof(char*);
}
```

And then calling `tableLength(table);` the result will be 1 instead of 4 as your program can not know the actual size of the table you are inserting.

But there are other means such like you can add an extra `NULL` at the end of array so you would declare it as:

```
static const char *table[] = {
    "text a",
    "text b",
    "text c",
    "text d",
    NULL
};
```

And then to get a count of such table you would have:

```
int tableLength(const char *stringTable[]) {
    for(int i=0;; i++) if(stringTable[i]==NULL) return i;
}
```

In your case you will probably need to figure out how the strings are layout in the table to see which procedure to use. But most usually you get a number somewhere in the function indicating the number of strings in the table.

Comment: Ok thank you for the reply.Can we get the count from const char* tables[]?. I mean number of objects in const char* tables?